# Function not scaling correctly

Tags: bash

I want to round to 2 decimal places but it does not calculate correctly.

```
score() {
    read -p "Enter the quiz score, homework score, and exam score: " quiz home exam

    echo "scale=2; ((( $quiz + $home + $exam )/135)*100)" | bc
}
```

If you enter the values `5 10 15` into the equation it should spit out 22.22 but mine spits out 22.00. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're losing the decimals when bc multiplies the intermediate result of `0.22` with `100`. If you switch place with the multiplication and the division you will end up with the desired output, or you can also replace both of them by just dividing by `1.35`.